# Binding Filter results to input fails in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code is like this

```
<body ng-app="">
<div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                       {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                       {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                       {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                       {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                       {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>Name only
<input ng-model="search.name">
<br>
    <h3>Results</h3>
<table id="searchObjResults">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
     name:   <input ng-model="friendObj.name" />
        <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
         <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

when any search happens I want to bind result data to an input box I provided. Filtering happpens correctly, but i am not able to bind it to my input. it correctly binds to a `<td>` though.
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyugb3fw/)** 
Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Chandermani is correct with tr and td: http://jsfiddle.net/eyugb3fw/1/

Comment: @LearningNeverStops I have to wait 2 more minutes to mark it as correct answer. I am helpless ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input should be inside one of the `td` i think. See this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/u08xucsj/

Remember `tr` can only have `td`